# jQuery animation affects content below (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome

I've create an affect that runs when a row of icons are visible on screen.

The animation is essentially changing the `padding` of a `div`, giving the effect of a pulse from the icons.

It works perfectly in every browser except Chrome (surprisingly!). Chrome for some reason wobbles the text under each icon while it animates. I used `padding` in the hopes that it would only affect the content within the `div` (using the `box-sizing: border-box` model).

I did write a fix for it which works in Chrome but then breaks the layout in Safari.

So I'm not sure if I can fix the wobble in Chrome or if I can alter my fix to help Safari out.

[Here's the link to the page as it is at the moment](http://apt.codeplayground.co.uk/), without the jQuery fix. It's in the JS file but commented out.

Here's the code that runs the animation, the fix is in here, just commented out:

```
$('.wrapper').scroll(function(e) {

    var tTop = target.offset().top;
    var tTopOffset = tTop+target.height();

    if( tTop < height ) {

        if (flag) {

            targetDiv.animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 500);


            targetDiv.each(function(i){

                // FIX breaks on safari, but fixes issue in Chrome...
                // targetDiv.css('height', targetDivHeight);

                $(this).delay((i++) * 900).animate({
                    padding: '0em'
                }, 400);


                $(this).animate({
                    padding: '0.5em'
                }, 400);

            }); 

            flag = false

        }


    } else {

        targetDiv.css('opacity', '0');
        flag = true;

    }

});
```

Comment: Why are you animating padding? Wouldn't it be better to animate the icon with a tranform: scale(1.3); for example?

Comment: I figured if I animate the padding it wont affect any of the elements below it as it'll be constrained to the containing div, because of the box model. But Chrome isn't playing ball for some reason.

Comment: that's exactly what transform scale is for, animating elements without interfering with the layout.

Answer (score 5):

I think it is because you didn't specified the width and height of the element you are trying to animate. border-box doesn't just ignore padding value, it needs width and height value that includes padding and border. Using transform:scale could be nice either as commented above, but IMHO it is a bit tricky to achieve with .animate() and has less browser support.

Try this in console and try modify your code. I tried and it works well in the latest Safari and Chrome. (should use .outerHeight() to get correct value, since you use padding value to animate)

```
$ = jQuery;
var targetDiv = $('.icon-img-div');
var targetDivHeight = $('.icon-img-div').outerHeight();
var targetDivWidth = $('.icon-img-div').outerWidth();

targetDiv.each(function (i) {

    // this breaks on safari, but fixes issue in Chrome...
    targetDiv.css({
        height: targetDivHeight,
        width: targetDivWidth
    });

    $(this).delay((i++) * 900).animate({
        padding: '0em'
    }, 400);

    $(this).animate({
        padding: '0.5em'
    }, 400);

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Doesn't seem to be working though. Initially I thought it was but still no-go on Safari!

Comment: @lukeseager Can you elaborate what happens in Safari? Or any chance of screenshot? :) I don't experience any layout crash in Safari 7.0 while excuting my code above.